# "Powers" of injective representations "contain" all irreducibles

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ be an injective representation. I need to prove that each irreducible representation of $G$ is contained in $\otimes_{i=1}^{n} \rho$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (the tensor product of two representations $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ and $\varphi : G \to GL(W)$ is given by $\rho\otimes\varphi : G \ni g \mapsto \rho(g)\otimes \varphi(g) \in GL(V \otimes W)$).

I don't know how to do this, in particular, I don't see how the injectivity hypothesis can be applied. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\chi_{\rho^{\otimes n}} = \chi_\rho^n$.  So, if $\varphi$ is another representation, $\langle \varphi, \chi_{\rho^{\otimes n}} \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_g \chi_\varphi(g) (\overline{\chi_\rho (g)})^n$.  We can write this as $\sum_b a_b b^n$ for some distinct $b$ and constants $a_b$.

Since the functions $\{b^n\}$ are linearly independent, if we had $\langle \varphi, \chi_{\rho^{\otimes n}} \rangle=0$ for all $n$, we would have $a_b=0$ for all $b$.  In particular, $a_d=0$, where $d=\dim \rho$.  But $\rho$ is injective, so $\chi_\rho(g)=d \iff g=1$, and we have $a_d = \frac{1}{|G|} \chi_\varphi(1)$.  Therefore $\dim \varphi = \chi_\varphi (1)=0$, so $\varphi = 0$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why $\rho$ injective implies that $\chi_{\rho}(g) = d$ if and only if $g=1$?

Comment: @GenoWhirl $\chi_\rho (g) = d$ implies that all of the eigenvalues of $\chi_\rho (g)$ are $1$, since they all lie on the unit circle.  Since some power of $\chi_\rho (g)$ is $I$, this means that $\chi_\rho (g) = I$. (as a side note, my last paragraph was flawed, so I've removed it)